# qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed

Tags: qt, post, qt5, ssl

Возникла некоторая проблема следующего рода. Имеется приложение, осуществляющее post и get запросы, все функционирует адекватно, но лишь с http, если же обращение идет через https, то Qt вываливает ошибку qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed. После гугленья проблемы узнал, что, возможно, отсутствуют SSL библиотеки, отсюда вопрос, где это дело раздобыть и как подключить к проекту? Буду благодарен любым подсказкам, на всякий случай прикладываю свой код

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString A, B, C, X, Z;
    QByteArray data= "{ \"Authorization\":\"Bearer AQAAAAAGX9TiAATuwa8z\" }";
    A=ui->lineEdit->text(); //широта
    B=ui->lineEdit_2->text(); //долгота
    C=ui->lineEdit_3->text(); // масштаб
    X= "https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll="+B+","+A+"&z="+C+"&size=600,450&l=map"; //сначала долгота
    ui->preview->load(QUrl(X));
    ui->preview->show();

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWindow::onResult);
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://mdb.api.cloud.yandex.net/managed-postgresql/v1/clusters/c9qmjpt4v23oohbuj1vu/databases/db1"));
//    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.evileg.ru/it_example.json")));
    manager->get(request);
//    manager->post(request, data);


}

void MainWindow::onResult(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
        QByteArray json_data = reply->readAll();
        ui->textEdit->setPlainText(json_data)
       }
    else {
        qDebug() << "error: " << reply->error();
    }
       reply->deleteLater();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>

#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QUrlQuery>
#include <QUrl>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void onResult(QNetworkReply *reply);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Итак, для пользователей **Windows** и компилятора от **MSVC**, в случае возникновения подобной проблемы, могу порекомендовать сделать следующие вещи:
1. Отсюда [Win32/Win64 OpenSSL Installer for Windows](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) скачивается Win32 OpenSSL 1.0.2 соответствующей версии ***(x64 для msvc2017_64 и x32 для msvc2017_32, версия студии может быть иная)***, можно качать light.
2. Устанавливаем Win32 OpenSSL.
3. Из корневой папки установленного ранее OpenSLL вынимаем файлы libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll, ssleay32.dll и отправляем их по пути \Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017\bin ***(версии Qt и MSVC могут различаться)***, отправляем в соответствии с разрядностью.
4. Проверяем работоспособность

Мне такой вариант помог.

Comment: лучший, мне помог именно третий шаг, все же говорят кидать к исполняемому файлу, а тут нужно было в папку самого комплиятор

Comment: Ваш вариант не помог, но помог этот:
https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread2456250.html

Comment: @РоманХудобердин, интересно, учитывая то, что там описано один в один идентичное решение)

Answer (score 3):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed` когда переносил всё в виртуалку. Копировать либы каждый раз в папку с Qt не слишком удобно, забыть проще простого, особенно, что версия меняется часто. Поэтому, в том [инсталлере](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-1_0_2r.exe) надо отметить пункт копировать всё в Windows.

**Обновление**: Qt 5.14 принёс с собой собранный OpenSSL (`Qt\Tools\OpenSSL`). Чтобы избавиться от `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed` добавил в `PATH` путь `%QTDIR%/../../Tools/OpenSSL/Win_x64/bin`

Comment: Просто ставим и указываем галку копировать в системные папки Windows.

Comment: А если требуется общая папка с виртуалкой? Да и засорять систему - зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится...
Столкнулся тут недавно с тем что на одном ПК ни в какую не хотели загружаться SSL библиотеки libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll и libssl-1_1-x64.dll. Как оказалось они зависят от vcruntime140.dll которая содержится в пакете Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Update 3 RC.
Можно соответственно требовать установки всего этого пакета, но я у себя просто включил в состав приложения эту самую vcruntime140.dll и все работает!