# Qt Не работает функционал собранного проекта

Tags: windows, qt, парсер, qtcreator, сборка

Сделал проект, решил выпустить в релиз. Воспользовался программой windeployqt для сборки всех нужных файлов для работы exe-файла.В итоге вроде и запускается, но при нажатии на кнопку, отвечающую за функционал(а именно парсинг) моментально прогружаются пустые страницы.[image: исполняемый файл с собранными библиотеками] Вот так выглядит результат работы исполняемого файла вне qt:[image: Попытка запуска собранной программы] А на третьем скриншоте рабочий вариант, запускающийся через qt.[image: Корректный вариант работы проекта в режиме debug в Qt Creator]. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Парсинг чего? Откуда данные поступают берутся?

Comment: Данные беру с e-katalog.Просто запросы на сайт и загрузка html с последующей обработкой.

Comment: Проблема может быть в блокировке запроса со стороны ос. А может быть из-за файла настроек, например, или у вас жестко забит адрес в коде?

Comment: Да,в коде прописаны конкретные адреса. Если проблема именно в том,что сама система не дает отправить запросы,что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение при попытке запустить проект на другом пк. Из-за того, что отправлялись запросы по протоколу https, надо было установить OpenSSL и закинуть две библиотеки в папку с exe.А именно libssl-1_1x64.dll и libcrypto-1_1x64.dll. То, что я делал это в самом начале разработки проекта я благополучно забыл. Собственно, решение:
[qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952577/qt-network-ssl-qsslsocketconnecttohostencrypted-tls-initialization-failed)